# How to trigger function after settimeout done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I trigger my ajax function after setTimeout done ?

I have ajax function and I want to trigger it after my box showing I tried inside setTimeout function, it didn't work properly it works both before settimeout and after settimeout and I only need to trigger it after settimeout done or I tell you like this:

When my settimeout works than my ajax function must

```js
function canliDestekOpen(e) {
    var boxDel = $(e).attr("data-delay");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".canli-destek").fadeIn();

         /*
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/showinvite",
            method: "post",
            success: function(data) {

            }
        });
*/
        
    }, parseInt(boxDel) * 1000);
}
canliDestekOpen(".canli-destek");
```

```css
.canli-destek {
  display: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 398px;
  height: 112px;
  border: 2px solid #faa82b;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.canli-destek .canli-destek-inner {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: absolute;
}
.canli-destek .canli-destek-inner span {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.canli-destek h6 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #222222;
}
.canli-destek p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #4e4e4e;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.canli-destek button {
  background: #012770;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  padding: 6px 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.canli-destek .canli-destek-kapat {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #faa82b;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="canli-destek" data-delay="3">
        <div class="canli-destek-inner">
            <button data-link="http://www.google.de">Start Conversation</button>
        </div>
        <div class="canli-destek-kapat">
            <span class="ani-icon-error-1 canli-kapat-icon">X</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Put the function call at the last line of the function in settimeout

Comment: can't you do something like `canliDestekOpen(".canli-destek").then(function() { nameofyourfunction() })` Or you can simple put the function at the very end of the setTimeOut

Comment: @Rajesh how ? @Carsten Lovbo Andersen I haven't hear before then function I tried this `canliDestekOpen(".canli-destek").then({
    myFunction()
});`

and it gave me a this error line `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
`

Comment: @ani_css `.then` is a part of `promise`. And look for a term, `callback chaining`. Its like this `setTimeout(function(){  your code...; functionToBeExecuted(); }, delay)`

Comment: @Rajesh my function is already like your example

Comment: @ani_css You are making an AJAX request. That is again a async function. You will have to pass functionToBeCalled to it and call it on last line of `success` function. Hence **`callback chain`**

Comment: oow I understand so how can we apply it with my js function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want

jQuery's `.fadeIn` is an asynchronous function, which means that execution of code will proceed after triggering the `fadeIn`, without waiting for it to finish.

If you want your AJAX to be called after `fadeIn` is done then pass it as a function argument to .fadeIn

```
$(".canli-destek").fadeIn(function (){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/showinvite",
        method: "post",
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about my answer

Whether data-delay is returning a string or number?. Whether it is converting from string to parseInt?.

Try this

```
$( e ).data( "delay" )
```